# Which route should I calculate in this graph exercise?

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, algorithms

The problem is the following:

A car rental company is developing a fleet renewal plan for the next four years. It has been decided that newly acquired vehicles must be replaced after a minimum of one year of use or a maximum of three. The replacement costs in Euros are indicated in the following table.

[image: Table]

So, they asked me to make the graph with the data in the table. And with the help they gave me I managed to make the following graph.

[image: Graph]

But now, I am asked to determine the strategy that minimizes the replacement costs of the vehicle fleet in a horizon of four years. So, this would be to find the shortest path using Dijkstra's algorithm between the years 2022 to 2025 and from 2023 to 2026 and get the shortest path between these two?